# Why the AstroNvim editor cursor in st is not normal

Tags: archlinux, st, x-dwm

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3iJFL.png)

As the image showing the cursor of the steady bar is not normal. The block bar is OK. Should I change the font or something else? The cursor drifts up and there are still remnants. But there's no problem with the editing steady cursor in emacs.